# Adding timer to the text box

Tags: c#, timer, textbox

I have created 2 dictionaries. One dictionary I am saving the information on it. Then I am going to sort the information in that  dictionary according the value. Then, I am going to save the information in the second dictionary. I am going to display the information from the second Dictionary. What I want is that one piece on information is going to appear every 3 seconds. Can I do that?

```
//intialize to get and set the coodrdinats 
int xCoor;
int yCoor;
int prioritySaver;
int timeSaver;

//Intialize the Dictionaries
Dictionary<int, int> pQueuValues = new Dictionary<int, int>();

//Intialize the Lists
List<int> saveRandomTime = new List<int>();
List<int> randomListxCoor = new List<int>();
List<int> randomListyCoor = new List<int>(); 

private void PQueue(int nodenum)
{
    for (int x = 1; x <= nodenum; x++)
    {
        xCoor = coor.Next(0, 700);
        yCoor = coor.Next(0, 730);
        if (!randomListxCoor.Contains(xCoor))
        {
            randomListxCoor.Add(xCoor);
        }
        if (!randomListyCoor.Contains(xCoor))
        {
            randomListyCoor.Add(yCoor);
        }
        prioritySaver = pQueuNumbers.Next(1, nodenum*3);
        timeSaver = randomTime.Next(1, 201);

        //Add the values t the Dictionaries and the List.
        pQueuValues.Add(x, prioritySaver);
    }

    //Sort the Dictionary 
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Int32> savePQ in pQueuValues.OrderBy(key => key.Value))
    {
        txtOutput.Text += "\r\n\n" + "The node number  :" + savePQ.Key + "  Has the Prority:  " + savePQ.Value;
    }
    //I want the timer the show the infroamtion from the sorted dictionary.

}
}
```

I was thinking to do things also like this. But I am getting problem with the following code that in prints all the value in the dictionary. I want it to print one value at a time.

```
//Sort the Dictionary 
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Int32> savePQ in pQueuValues.OrderBy(key => key.Value))
{
    pQueueOrdered.Add(savePQ.Key, savePQ.Value);

    //txtOutput.Text += "\r\n\n" + "The node number  :" + savePQ.Key + "  Has the Prority:  " + savePQ.Value;
}

var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
int track = 0;
timer.Tick += (timerObject, timerArgs) =>
{
    timer.Interval = 3000;
    txtOutput.Text += "\r\n\n" + "The node number  :" + pQueueOrdered.ContainsKey(track) + "  Has the Prority:  " + pQueueOrdered[track];
}
++track;
if (track > nodenum+1)
{
    timer.Stop();
    timer.Dispose();
    this.txtOutput.Text += "\r\r\n" + "  Ends x " + track.ToString();
}
};
timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Onik for the last editing you made it much cleaner to understand

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you have now and the vague description and the fact that your blob of code is not compileable I think this is close to what you need. I assume you want to click on a button to start the timer and keep everything contained within the OnClick event of the button.

```
    public void Button1_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 3000;    // every 3 seconds

        int track = 0; // where are we, aka the index

        txtOutput.Text = String.Empty;
        var output = new StringBuilder(); // use a stringbuilder 

        timer.Tick += (timerObject, timerArgs) =>
        {
             // check if track exists 
             // I couldn't find the type of pQueueOrdered so
             // I hope this works
             // otherwise track<=nodeNum might be an alternative
             if (pQueueOrdered.ContainsKey(track))
             {
                 output.AppendFormat(String.Format(
                     "\r\n\nThe node number  :{0}   Has the Prority:  {1}",  
                     pQueueOrdered.ContainsKey(track),
                     pQueueOrdered[track]));
                 txtOutput.Text = output.ToString();
                 // increase track to get the next
                 // item at the next Tick
                 track++;
             }
             // stop if done... 
             if (track > nodenum+1)
             {
                 timer.Stop();
                 output.AppendFormat(String.Format(
                    "\r\r\n  Ends x {0}",
                    track));
                 txtOutput.Text =  output.ToString();
             }
         }

         timer.Start();
    }
```

Comment: No I have one button to do everything

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little bit hard to follow. You're updating variables that don't get used, for example.

In any case, you should look at using Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this. (NuGet "Rx-Main".)

Here's the code you'd need as I can best determine:

```
private Random rnd = new Random();

private void PQueue(int nodenum)
{
    var txtOutput_Text = "";

    var queue =
        from x in Enumerable.Range(1, nodenum)
        let v = new { x, ps = rnd.Next(1, nodenum * 3) }
        orderby v.ps
        select v;

    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .Zip(queue.ToObservable(), (i, v) => v)
        .ObserveOn(txtOutput)
        .Subscribe(v =>
        {
            txtOutput.Text +=
                "\r\n\n"
                + "The node number  :" + v.x
                + "  Has the Prority:  " + v.ps;
        }, () =>
        {
            txtOutput.Text +=
                "\r\r\n"
                + "  Ends x " + nodenum.ToString();
        });
}
```